# setAttribute null in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, svg, safari, webkit

So I'm trying to append the innerHtml of a specific element. Im adding masks to the mask element whenever a person clicks a specific area of the image(collects coordinates and creates a mask based upon those coordinates). Essentially I'm adding more and more masks everytime the user clicks the image. I have it functioning just fine with Chrome, however, in safari it is rendering the new newly created Circle mask as Null. I imagine it has something to do with how safari renders certain html elements and how chrome does. Am i wrong in thinking this, and if so how would i go about adjusting this so that it works properly for both/all browsers.

```
function addMask(event) {
            var x = event.clientX;
            var y = event.clientY;
            idName = x+y;

            //new mask is added here by appending innerHTML
            document.getElementById("mask1").innerHTML += "<circle id='" + idName +"' r='30' fill='url(#grad1)'/>";
            //This is the object that gets rendered Null in Safari only.
            var circleObject = document.getElementById(idName); 

            circleObject.setAttribute("cx", x);
            circleObject.setAttribute("cy", y);
            alert(document.getElementById("mask1").innerHTML);
} 

<svg width="1000" height="835">

<defs>
<mask id="mask1" x="0" y="0" width="1000" height="835" >
  <defs>
            <filter id="f1" x="0" y="0">
              <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="8" />
            </filter>
            <radialGradient id="grad1" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%" fx="50%" fy="50%">
              <stop offset="50%" style="stop-color:rgb(0,0,0); stop-opacity:2" />
              <stop offset="75%" style="stop-color:rgb(0,0,0); stop-opacity:1" />
              <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(0,0,0);stop-opacity:0" />
            </radialGradient>
        </defs>
  <rect id="rectMask" x="0" y="0" width="1000" height="835" fill="#FFFFFF"/>
  <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="30" fill="url(#grad1)" />


</mask>
</defs>

<image onclick="addMask(event)" id="imageID" width="1000" height="835" xlink:href="RiftMapDarkSmall.png"  />

</svg>
```

Comment: I don't understand why you use *innerHTML* to create the circle element, then use *setAttribute* to set attributes. It would be better to either use all DOM methods or do it all using *innerHTML*.

Comment: good point, thanks... is one method preferred over the other?

Comment: that solved the null error...thanks. However, upon click its not refreshing the added masks, where as in Chrome it does? thoughts?

Comment: Dunno, I don't know much about SVG. I hope you've changed to DOM methods, Safari doesn't seem to like *innerHTML* with SVG elements.